# How to parse Dynamic nested JSON with same keys and store in JAVA Class

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I'm trying to read a complex payload(Tree structure) to perform PATCHMAPPING(Partial Update). To start with, I'm reading a JSON from the payload and trying to parse and store it's value.

**JSON DATA:**

```
{
  "data": [{
      "name": "name_new",
      "description": "new_decsription",
      "group_id": 1,
      "values": [{
          "inner_group_id": 1,
          "addclass_id": [1],
          "removeclass_id": [2, 3]
        },
        {
          "inner_group_id": 2,
          "addclass_id": [1],
          "removeclass_id": [2, 3]
        },
        {
          "addclass_id": [1],
          "removeclass_id": [2, 3]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group_id": 2,
      "values": [{
        "inner_group_id": 2,
        "addclass_id": [1, 2, 3],
        "removeclass_id": []
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

**NOTE:** group_id might have inner_group_id and have classes to remove and classes to add. But it can also directly have classes to remove and classes to add.

I'm using following code to parse it and trying to save in a HASHMAP. But it's not parsing properly.Also, I'm unsure if I save in hashmap, how will I tag each inner_group to it's group or class_id's to it's group.

```
    public static List<Map<String, String>> getKeyValue(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        
        Iterator<?> keys;
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
        List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        HashMap role = new HashMap();
        HashMap group = new HashMap();
         for (int i = 0, size = data.length(); i < size; i++)
            {
              JSONObject objectInArray = data.getJSONObject(i);
              keys = objectInArray.keys();
                    while(keys.hasNext())
                    {
                        String nextKeys = (String) keys.next();
                        if (objectInArray.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONArray)
                        {
                            JSONArray jsonarray = objectInArray.getJSONArray(nextKeys);
                            for(int ii=0; ii<jsonarray.length();ii++)
                            { 
                                String jsonarrayString =  jsonarray.getString(ii).toString();
                                JSONObject innerJSON = new JSONObject(jsonarrayString);
                                String[] elementNames = JSONObject.getNames(innerJSON);

                                  for (String elementName : elementNames)
                                  { 
                                     String value = innerJSON.getString(elementName);
                                     group.put(elementName, value);
                                  }
                            }

                    }

             String[] elementNames = JSONObject.getNames(objectInArray);
            // System.out.println(elementNames);
            //  System.out.printf("%d ELEMENTS IN CURRENT OBJECT:\n", elementNames.length);
              for (String elementName : elementNames){ 
                  String value = objectInArray.getString(elementName);
                  role.put(elementName, value);
              }
              listOfMaps.add(role);
              listOfMaps.add(group);

            }
}
        return listOfMaps;

}
```

I have made 2 JAVA Classes to set those after I can parse:

**Group.java**

```
public class Group {
    int groupId;
    List<InnerGroup> innerGroups;
    List<Integer> addClassId;
    List<Integer> removeClassId;
    
    // Getters and Setters
    }

**InnerGroup.java**

public class InnerGroup {
    int innerGroupId;
    List<Integer> addClassId;
    List<Integer> removeClassId;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

I have been stuck on this from last 2 days. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with PATCHMAPPING?

Comment: @JRichardsz - It's a way to partially update the data at backend through API. Check out this for more detail https://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring

Comment: After formatting your json I can see "X" rows each one with an array of values. If this is your initial entity, how could be partial modified? more rows? more values in a row? update any id on values? In your link there is an example : **Now, let's say that address field will often be updated by the client. In that case, we don't want to send the whole HeavyResource object with all fields...** What is the analogy in your case?

Answer (score 0):

The classes below, use Jackson to deserialize the JSON. The below is provided to give an idea of how to parse the JSON provided and may not necessarily be a complete solution.

**Entity Classes**

```
package org.test;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GroupContainer {
    
    @JsonProperty(value = "data")
    private List<Group> data;

    public List<Group> getData() {return data;}
    public void setData(List<Group> data) {this.data = data;}

}//class closing
```

---

```
    package org.test;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Group {
    
        @JsonProperty(value = "group_id")
        private int id=-1;
        
        @JsonProperty(value = "name")
        private String name;
        
        @JsonProperty(value = "description")
        private String description;
        
        @JsonProperty(value = "values")
        private List<InnerGroup> values;
    
        public int getId() {return id;}
        public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}
    
        public String getName() {return name;}
        public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    
        public String getDescription() {return description;}
        public void setDescription(String description) {this.description = description;}
    
        public List<InnerGroup> getValues() {return values;}
        public void setValues(List<InnerGroup> values) {this.values = values;}
    
      }//class closing
```

---

```
package org.test;

import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class InnerGroup {
    
    @JsonProperty(value = "inner_group_id")
    private int id=-1;
    
    @JsonProperty(value = "removeclass_id")
    private List<Integer> removeClassIds;
    
    @JsonProperty(value = "addclass_id")
    private List<Integer> addClassIds;

    public int getId() {return id;}
    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

    public List<Integer> getRemoveClassIds() {return removeClassIds;}
    public void setRemoveClassIds(List<Integer> removeClassIds) {this.removeClassIds = removeClassIds;}

    public List<Integer> getAddClassIds() {return addClassIds;}
    public void setAddClassIds(List<Integer> addClassIds) {this.addClassIds = addClassIds;}

}//class closing
```

**Parser Class**

```
package org.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonParseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        
        File jsonFile=new File("D:\\etc\\testworkspace\\ExpJavaProject\\etc\\str.json");
        try(FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(jsonFile)){
            
            GroupContainer container=mapper.readValue(fis, GroupContainer.class);
            
            //Test =================================
            System.out.println(container.getData());
            
            for(Group g:container.getData()) {

                System.out.println("Group Name --> "+g.getName());
                for(InnerGroup ig:g.getValues()) {
                    
                    System.out.println("\t\tInner Grp. ID --> "+ig.getId());
                    
                }//for closing
                
            }//for closing
            //END-Test =================================
            
        }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }//main closing

}//class closing
```

**NOTE:** Add the JSON provided above in the original post in a file of choice and change the path accordingly in the parser class to test.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.Thank you so much, It worked out for me! :)

Comment: Happy to hear, if you found the answer useful, you could consider accepting it.